# C Macro concatenation as function argument

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

I have a problem using a macro as a function parameter.

I have this macro:

```
#define PD13 GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_13
```

`GPIOD` and `GPIO_Pin_13` are macros too.

```
#define GPIO_Pin_13 ((uint16_t)0x2000)
#define GPIOD  ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOD_BASE)
```

in which `GPIOD_BASE` is a memory address.

I'm using it as argument for this function:

```
PinType initPin(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {
PinType pin;
if (GPIOx == GPIOA) {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
} else if (GPIOx == GPIOB) {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
} else if (GPIOx == GPIOC) {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
} else if (GPIOx == GPIOD) {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
} else {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOE, ENABLE);
}
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
GPIO_Init(GPIOx, &GPIO_InitStructure);
GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOx, GPIO_Pin);
pin.GPIO_Reg = GPIOx;
pin.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin;
pin.status = 1;
return pin;
}
PinType p1
p1 = initPin(PD13);
```

In this way everything works well, but if I try to add an argument to the `initPin` function, like:

```
void initPin(PinType *pin, GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {
if (GPIOx == GPIOA) {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
} else if (GPIOx == GPIOB) {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
} else if (GPIOx == GPIOC) {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
} else if (GPIOx == GPIOD) {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
} else {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOE, ENABLE);
}
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
GPIO_Init(GPIOx, &GPIO_InitStructure);
GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOx, GPIO_Pin);
pin->GPIO_Reg = GPIOx;
pin->GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin;
pin->status = 1;
}

PinType p1;
initPin(&p1, PD13);
```

The arguments are messed up and are incorrect.

Is there any way so I can use a macro for passing a part of the arguments while the others are passed normally?

Comment: We should see all that macros...

Comment: You should start by using `gcc -E` to look at your program after macro expansion if you haven't already done so.

Comment: In the first form, initPin() gets two args, in the second it gets three. What is the prototype for initPin()?

Comment: Any reason why you are obsfucating your code this way?

Comment: Please be more specific about the problem you are experiencing, and include the definition of GPIOD. The preprocessor should work just fine in the way you are using it, although human readers might find themselves confused.

Comment: Anyway the problem is not the function itself, is just how the arguments are passed.

Comment: "*in which `GPIOD` and `GPIO_Pin_13` are macros too*": You miss to show us `GPIOD` but instead show us `IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH`.

Comment: Ok sorry I finally found it!    #define GPIOD               ((GPIO_TypeDef *) GPIOD_BASE)

Comment: Now can you be more precise about the problem? Are you getting a compiler error? If so, what is the error? Or do you think that the wrong values are being passed? If so, why?

Comment: Ok, i'm writing a program for STM32F4-Discovery board, when i compile the program i receive no errors, but using the debugger i can see clearly that the values passed to the initPin functions are not the expected ones (for example GPIO_Pin should be 0x2000 and instead it is 0xc000)

Comment: This mostly likely has nothing to with the use of macros. Does it work if you write the same code without macros? What does `gcc -E mysource.c` or `cpp mysource.c` give you?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way so I can use a macro for passing a part of the
>   arguments while the others are passed normally?

No. Macro expansion is entirely textual and there are no mechanisms to suppress expansion of selected arguments.

You could, however, define different macros to achieve a similar effect:

```
#define PD13_2args GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_13
#define PD13_1arg  GPIO_Pin_13
initPin(PD13_2args);
initPin(&p1, PD13_1arg);
```

You might also want to read about *variadic macros*, a feature available with C99 and later, in conjunction with variadic functions (e.g. like `printf`).

Comment: I don't want to use just one argument from the macro. I want to use the macro in the same way i used it before, but modifying the function to accept 3 arguments, the first is passed normally, the other 2 by the macro.

Comment: @PaulRox And what should happen to the third argument? You mean a two argument version of initPin(x,y) should ignore the third when called as initPin(x,y,z) after macro expansion? It is hard to tell what you want.

Comment: No no, initially i made the initPin function like the first i wrote in the post, with 2 arguments and returning a PinType variable, then i wanted to give the PinType structure to the function passing it as reference, so i changed the code of the function as you can see in the post. So, the problem is that the first version of the function was working well, while the second version isn't working because the arguments passed using the macro are wrong.

Comment: @PaulRox So you have refactored the code so that initPin() got an argument prepended? What exactly does "isn't working" mean? Is there a compile time error? Then provide the error message. Is there a run-time error? Then provide some info. Did you recompile *all* files after refactoring? In the code shown, the arguments passed using the macro are NOT "wrong". There is something you don't tell us.

Comment: Now it's working! I still don't understand where the problem was, anyway, i'm using Eclipse and i've tried to make "Clean Project" before building it and now it seems to work as expected. All the other times i tried to build the project i checked that all the changed files was re-compiled, so i really don't understand why it should work doing "Clean Project" before compiling.

Comment: Are you saying that the root of the problem is not knowing how to use eclipse to re-factor a project, because the re-factoring you did was not complete?     Need to 'clean the project' so any existing object files are eliminated so all objects are re-compiled with the latest re-factored code.